# Errors compiling with gfortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have copied a FORTRAN 66/IV program from a 1988 report, and I am trying to compile it with gfortran (mingw for windows). I have reduced a long list of errors down to 3 (plus 2 warnings), and I cannot get any further despite my best efforts. I would be grateful for any help and advice.

The errors:

```
green.f:298.16:
RDE=(EXPR(J)/REYLOC(J)-EXPR(J-1)/REYLOC(J-1))/ZDIFF
         1
Error: PROCEDURE attribute conflicts with COMMON attribute in 'expr' at (1)
green.f:412.7:
1,5X,F10.4)
  1
Error: Nonnegative width required in format string at (1)
green.f:390.19:
WRITE(OUT,11)(Z(J),CUR(J),CP(J),PH(J),RMSQ(J),U(J),Q(J),J=1,P)
            1
Error: FORMAT label 11 at (1) not defined
green.f:249.61:
CALL OPTION(MSQLOC,RAD,LOCR,RDASH,X,Y,FEQ,HALFCO,H,H1,IMBAL,
                                                     1
Warning: Type mismatch in argument 'imbalcrxn' at (1); passed REAL(4) to INTEGER(4)
green.f:122.72:
1OUT)
                                                                        1
Warning: Missing actual argument for argument 'out' at (1)
```

This is the source code:

```
00000001     PROGRAM GREEN
00000002     REAL TRAD(100),CUR(100),V(100),EXPR(100),Z(100),MSQ(100),U(100)
00000003    1,XX(100),REYLOC(100),Y(3),YDASH(3),AA(21),NU,INCR,LSCALE,LAT,
00000004    2IMB,LIMIT,MINF,MINFSQ,Z1(100),LOCR,MSQLOC,Q(100),PH(100),
00000005    3CP(100),RI(100),RSTAR(100),RK(100),FACT,TW(100),DR(100),DRAG,
00000006    4XEXP(20),DEXP(20),THEXP(20),HEXP(20),FCEXP(20),DSTP(100),
00000007    5THPLT(100),HPLT(100),CFPLT(100)
00000008     INTEGER AXIS,COND,CURV,FSTART,STRET,DIL,P,HQ,TQ,DEV,SURF,OUT
00000009    1,P1,NSTA
00000010     CHARACTER*8 LABEL
00000011     COMMON/CB1/AXIS,CURV,COND,FSTART,STRET,DIL,P,DEV,JTE,RATIO
00000012     COMMON/CB2/REC,TRAD,UDASH,Z,J,U,RK
00000013     COMMON/CB3/CUR,EXPR,REYLOC
00000014     COMMON/CB4/MINFSQ,TINF,RC
00000015     COMMON/CB5/RTHETA,THETA,FEQ,HALFC,CRXN,H,H1,RICH,FACT
00000016      COMMON/CB6/MINF,TSTAG,M,TQ,HQ,IRPT,IDENT,KK,HDASH
00000017        COMMON/CB7/NSTA,XEXP,DEXP,THEXP,HEXP,CFEXP,P1,LABEL
00000018        CALL DIG
00000019        CALL SIMBEG
00000020      DEV=15
00000021      OUT=16
00000022      IRPT=1
00000023 35   CALL INPUT(TRAD,CUR,EXPR,V,Z,Z1,XX,Y1,Y2,RC,REC,SURF,LS,RK)
00000024      
00000025      
00000026     P1=P
00000027     Y(1)=Y1
00000028     Y(2)=Y2
00000029     WRITE(OUT,20)IDENT,MINF,RC
00000030     CALL EVALFP(PINF,HQINF,REC,Q,V,MSQ,U,P,REYLOC,PH,CP,RK)
00000031         
00000032         
00000033     IF(IRPT.GT.2)GOTO 21
00000034     CALL INDATA(Z,Z1,XX,CUR,PH,CP,MSQ,U,Q,SURF,AXIS,P,CURV,OUT,RK)
00000035         
00000036         
00000037 21  IF(HQ.NE.0)GOTO 14
00000038     H=(Y(1)+1)*(1+0.2*REC*MSQ(LS))-1
00000039     GOTO 15
00000040 14  H=Y(1)
00000041     Y(1)=(Y(1)+1)/(1+0.2*REC*MSQ(LS))-1
00000042 15  IF(TQ.NE.1) GOTO 16
00000043     Y(2)=Y(2)*TRAD(LS)
00000044     RTHETA=Y(2)*REYLOC(LS)/TRAD(LS)
00000045     GOTO 17
00000046 16  RTHETA=Y(2)
00000047     Y(2)=TRAD(LS)*Y(2)/REYLOC(LS)
00000048 17  J=LS+1
00000049     X=Z(LS)
00000050     CALL FUNC(5,YDASH,X,Y,LS)
00000051     
00000052     
00000053     RI(LS)=RICH
00000054     RSTAR(LS)=Y(2)
00000055     SLOPE=UDASH/U(LS)
00000056     DH1DHB=-1.72/(Y(1)-1)**2.0-0.2*(Y(1)-1)
00000057     IF(FSTART.EQ.0)GOTO 9
00000058     Y(3)=Y(2)*DH1DHB*HDASH/TRAD(LS)+H1*(HALFC-(H+1)*Y(2)*SLOP
00000059    1E/TRAD(LS))
00000060     Y(3)=Y(3)-CRXN/TRAD(LS)
00000061 9   CF=2*HALFC
00000062     TW(LS)=HALFC*1.2*REYLOC(LS)*REYLOC(LS)*1.51E-5*1.51E-5
00000063     RW3=THETA*H
00000064     G=SQRT(1/HALFC)*(1-1/Y(1))
00000065     PI=-H*THETA*UDASH/(U(LS)*HALFC)
00000066     CFS=CF*Q(LS)
00000067     IF(COND.EQ.0.AND.CURV.EQ.0.AND.STRET.EQ.0.AND.DIL.EQ.0)GOTO4
00000068     WRITE(OUT,5)
00000069     IF(COND.GT.0)WRITE(OUT,6)
00000070     IF(CURV.GT.0)WRITE(OUT,8)
00000071     IF(DIL.GT.0)WRITE(OUT,18)
00000072     IF(STRET.GT.0.AND.(AXIS.EQ.1.OR.COND.GT.0))WRITE(OUT,12)
00000073 4   IF(FSTART.GT.0)WRITE(OUT,11)HDASH
00000074     WRITE(OUT,2)
00000075     WRITE(OUT,3)Z1(LS),Y(1),CF,RTHETA,THETA,RW3,H,CFR,G,PI,Y(3),FEQ
00000076     
00000077     
00000078     DSTP(LS)=RW3
00000079     THPLT(LS)=THETA
00000080     HPLT(LS)=H
00000081     CFPLT(LS)=CF
00000082     
00000083     DEL=Z(LS+1)-Z(LS)
00000084     CALL STEP(YDASH,Y,DEL)
00000085     
00000086     
00000087     LL=LS+1
00000088     DRAG=0.0
00000089     DO 10 J=LL,P
00000090     
00000091     
00000092     SW1=Z(J)-Z(J-1)
00000093     LIMIT=Z(J)
00000094     IF(SQ1.LT.DEL)DEL=SW1
00000095 13  CALL VINT(3,DEL,X,Y,LIMIT,0.5E-5,1000,YDASH,AA,21,OUT,J)
00000096     
00000097     
00000098     IF(Y(3).LE.-0.009)Y(3)=-0.009
00000099     X=Z(J)
00000100     CALL FUNC(0,YDASH,X,Y,J)
00000101     CF=2.0*HALFC
00000102     TW(J)=HALFC*1.2*REYLOC(J)*REYLOC(J)*1.51E-5*1.51E-5
00000103     RSTAR(J)=Y(2)
00000104     RI(J)=RICH
00000105     RW3=THETA*H
00000106     CFR=CF*Q(J)
00000107     G=SQRT(1.0/HALFC)*(1.0-1/Y(1))
00000108     PI=-H*THETA*UDASH/(U(J)*HALFC)
00000109     DR(J)=((TW(J)+TW(J-1))/2)*(Z1(J)-Z1(J-1))*0.0325
00000110     DRAG=DRAG+DR(J)
00000111     WRITE(OUT,3)Z1(J),Y(1),CF,RTHETA,THETA,RW3,H,CFR,G,PI,Y(3),FEQ
00000112     
00000113     
00000114     DSTP(J)=RW3
00000115     THPLT(J)=THETA
00000116     HPLT(J)=H
00000117     CFPLT(J)=CF
00000118     
00000119 10  CONTINUE
00000120     WRITE(OUT,40)DRAG
00000121     IF(AXIS.EQ.1.OR.CURV.GT.0) CALL CUORAX(AXIS,CURV,P,RSTAR,RI,Z1,LS,
00000122    1OUT)
00000123     
00000124     
00000125     CALL ENDPLT
00000126     
00000127     READ(DEV,*)IRPT
00000128     IF(IRPT.GT.5)STOP
00000129     GOTO 35
00000130 2   FORMAT(3(/),1H ,5X,1HX,7X,2HHT,5X,5HCFLOC,4X,6HRTHETA,6X,5HTHETA
00000131    1,5X,7HDELSTAR,5X,1HH,6X,5HCFREF,8X,1HG,9X,2HPI,8X,1HF,7X,3HFEQ)
00000132 3   FORMAT(1H ,1PE10.3,1X,0PF6.3,1X,F8.5,1X,3(1PE10.3,1X),0PF7.3,1X,
00000133    1F8.5,1X,2(1PE10.3,1X),0PF8.5,1X,F8.5)
00000134 40  FORMAT(1H,20X,26HTOTAL SKIN FRICTION DRAG= ,F12.6)
00000135 5   FORMAT(1H0,20HALLOWANCES MADE FOR:)
00000136 6   FORMAT(1H ,20X,26HCONVERGENCE AND DIVERGENCE)
00000137 18  FORMAT(1H ,20X,10HDILATATION)
00000138 8   FORMAT(1H ,20X,22HLONGITUDINAL CURVATURE)
00000139 11  FORMAT(1H0,23HINITIAL VALUE OF DH/DX=,F9.4)
00000140 12  FORMAT(1H ,20X,18HLATERAL STRETCHING)
00000141 20  FORMAT(1H1,3X,73HLAG ENTRAINMENT B.L CALCULATION FOR TWO DIMENSION
00000142    1AL AND AXISYMMETRIC FLOW,5(/),1H,10HIDENT. NO.,1X,I5,5X,6HMINF= ,
00000143    2E11.4,5X,4HRC= ,E11.4)
00000144     STOP
00000145     END
00000146     
00000147     SUBROUTINE INPUT(TRAD,CUR,EXPR,V,Z,Z1,XX,Y1,Y2,RC,REC,SURF,LS,RK)
00000148     REAL TRAD(100),CUR(100),V(100),EXPR(100),Z(100),Z1(100),XX(100),
00000149    1MINF,RK(100),XEXP(20),DEXP(20),THEXP(20),HEXP(20),CFEXP(20)
00000150     INTEGER AXIS,COND,CURV,STRET,FSTART,DIL,P,SURF,DEV,TQ,HQ,NSTA,P1
00000151     CHARACTER*8 LABEL
00000152     COMMON/CB1/AXIS,CURV,COND,FSTART,STRET,DIL,P,DEV,JTE,RATIO
00000153     COMMON/CB6/MINF,TSTAG,M,TQ,HQ,IRPT,IDENT,KK,HDASH
00000154     COMMON/CB7/NSTA,XEXP,DEXP,THEXP,HEXP,CFEXP,P1,LABEL
00000155     GOTO(20,5,6,8,9),IRPT
00000156 20  READ(DEV,*)P,AXIS,SURF
00000157     READ(DEV,*)JTE
00000158     DO 10 J=1,P
00000159     TRAD(J)=1.0
00000160 10  CONTINUE
00000161     IF(SURF.EQ.0.AND.AXIS.EQ.0)GOTO 3
00000162     READ(DEV,*)(Z1(J),XX(J),J=1,P)
00000163     IF(AXIS.EQ.0) GOTO 4
00000164     DO 11 J=1,P
00000165     TRAD(J)=XX(J)
00000166 11  CONTINUE
00000167 4   IF(SURF.EQ.0)GOTO 1
00000168     Z(1)=0.0
00000169     DO 13 J=2,P
00000170     DELZ=Z1(J)-Z1(J-1)
00000171     DELX=XX(J)-XX(J-1)
00000172     Z(J)=SQRT(DELZ*DELZ*DELX*DELX)+Z(J-1)
00000173 13  CONTINUE
00000174     GOTO 5
00000175 3   READ(DEV,*)(Z1(J),J=1,P)
00000176 1   DO 14 J=1,P
00000177     Z(J)=Z1(J)
00000178 14  CONTINUE
00000179 5   READ(DEV,*)M
00000180     READ(DEV,*)(V(J),J=1,P)
00000181     READ(DEV,*)(RK(J),J=1,P)
00000182 6   READ(DEV,*)COND,CURV,STRET,FSTART,DIL
00000183     IF(COND.NE.1) GOTO7
00000184     READ(DEV,*)(EXPR(J),J=1,P)
00000185 7   IF(CURV.NE.1) GOTO 8
00000186     READ(DEV,*)(CUR(J),J=1,P)
00000187 8   READ(DEV,*)Y2,Y1,RC,MINF,TSTAG,REC
00000188     READ(DEV,*),TQ,HQ,LS
00000189 9   IF(FSTART.EQ.1) READ(DEV,*)HDASH
00000190     READ(DEV,*)IDENT
00000191     
00000192     
00000193     READ(DEV,*)LABEL
00000194     READ(DEV,*)NSTA
00000195     READ(DEV,*)(XEXP(I),I=1,NSTA)
00000196     READ(DEV,*)(DEXP(I),I=1,NSTA)
00000197     READ(DEV,*)(THEXP(I),I=1,NSTA)
00000198     READ(DEV,*)(HEXP(I),I=1,NSTA)
00000199     READ(DEV,*)(CFEXP(I),I=1,NSTA)
00000200     RETURN
00000201     END
00000202     
00000203     SUBROUTINE FUNC(N,YDASH,X,Y,LL)
00000204     REAL TRAD(100),CUR(100),Z(100),U(100),MSQLOC,LOCR,Y(3),YDASH(3),
00000205    1LAMDA,IMBAL,LAT,LSQ,NEWK,RK(100),FACT
00000206     INTEGER AX,CU,CO,FS,ST,DIL,P,DEV,LL
00000207     COMMON/CB1/AX,CU,CO,FS,ST,DIL,P,DEV,JTE,RATIO
00000208     COMMON/CB2/REC,TRAD,UDASH,Z,J,U,RK
00000209     COMMON/CB5/RTHETA,THETA,FEQ,HALFC,CRXN,H,H1,RICH,FACT
00000210     CRXN=0.0
00000211     LAMDA=1
00000212     IMBAL=0.0
00000213     RAD=1.0
00000214     SW1=Z(J)-Z(J-1)
00000215     IF(AX.GT.0)RAD=(TRAD(J-1)+(X-Z(J-1))*(TRAD(J)-TRAD(J-1))/SW1)
00000216     UDASH=(U(J)-U(J-1))/SW1
00000217     ULOC=U(J-1)+UDASH*(X-Z(J-1))
00000218     CALL VELMR(MSQLOC,TLOC,LOCR,ULOC)
00000219     
00000220     
00000221     IF(Y(1).GT.2.65)Y(1)=2.65
00000222     H=(1+Y(1))*(1+0.2*REC*MSQLOC)-1.0
00000223     THETA=Y(2)/RAD
00000224     DELTA=0.0
00000225 10  RTHETA=LOCR*THETA
00000226     
00000227     
00000228     FACT=1+(2000-RTHETA)*0.00003734
00000229     IF(FACT.LT.1.0)THEN
00000230     FACT=1.0
00000231     END IF
00000232     HALFCO=FACT*(0.005065/(0.4342945*ALOG(RTHETA*(1+.056*MSQLOC)
00000233    1)-1.02)-0.000375)/SQRT(1+0.2*MSQLOC)
00000234     
00000235     IF(J.GT.JTE)HALFCO=0
00000236     HBO=1/(1-6.55*SQRT(HALFCO*(1+0.04*MSQLOC)))
00000237     HALFC=HALFCO*(0.9/(Y(1)/HBO-0.4)-0.5)
00000238     CALL SFCR(HALFC,RK(LL),AAA)
00000239     
00000240     
00000241     HALFC=HALFC*AAA
00000242     IF(HALFC.LT.0.000001) HALFC=0.000001
00000243     H1=3.15+1.72/(Y(1)-1)-0.01*(Y(1)-1)**2.0
00000244     DH1DHB=-1.72/(Y(1)-1)**2.0-0.02*(Y(1)-1)
00000245     Q=((Y(1)-1.0)/(6.432*Y(1)))**2.0/(1.0+0.04*MSQLOC)
00000246     FEQ=H1*(HALFC-(H+1.0)*(HALFC-Q)/(0.8*H))
00000247     RDASH=RAD*HALFC-(H+2-MSQLOC)*Y(2)*UDASH/ULOC
00000248     DU=THETA*(H1+H)*UDASH/ULOC
00000249     CALL OPTION(MSQLOC,RAD,LOCR,RDASH,X,Y,FEQ,HALFCO,H,H1,IMBAL,
00000250    1CRXN,RICH,LAMDA,DU)
00000251     
00000252     
00000253     IF(FEQ.LT.0.0)FEQ=0.0
00000254     IF(N.EQ.0)RETURN
00000255     IF(N.EQ.5) Y(3)=FEQ
00000256     DUEQ=(H1+H)*(HALFC-FEQ/H1)/(H+1)
00000257     FMA=SQRT(1+0.1*MSQLOC)
00000258     FMB=1+0.075*MSQLOC*(1+0.2*MSQLOC)/(1+0.1*MSQLOC)
00000259     YDASH(1)=((RAD+DELTA)*Y(3)-RAD*(H1*HALFC)+H1*(H+1)*Y(2)*UDASH/
00000260    1ULOC+CRXN)/Y(2)/DH1DHB
00000261     YDASH(2)=RDASH+IMBAL
00000262     IF(Y(3).LE.-0.009)Y(3)=0.009
00000263     YDASH(3)=(Y(3)*(Y(3)+0.02)+0.5333*HALFCO)/(Y(3)+0.01)*(2.8*
00000264    1LAMDA*FMA*(SQRT(0.64*HALFCO+0.024*FEQ+1.2*FEQ*FEQ)-SQRT(0.64*
00000265    2HALFCO+0.024*Y(3)+1.2*Y(3)*Y(3)))+DUEQ-DU*FMB)/(Y(2)*(H1+H))
00000266 3   RETURN
00000267     END
00000268     
00000269     SUBROUTINE VELMR(MSQLOC,TLOC,LOCR,ULOC)
00000270     REAL MSQLOC,MINFSQ,LOCR
00000271     COMMON/CB4/MINFSQ,TINF,RC
00000272     MSQLOC=ULOC*ULOC*MINFSQ/(1+0.2*MINFSQ*(1-ULOC*ULOC))
00000273     TLOC=TINF*(1+0.2*MINFSQ)/(1+0.2*MSQLOC)
00000274     LOCR=RC*ULOC*TLOC/TINF*(TLOC+114)/(TINF+114)
00000275     RETURN
00000276     END
00000277     
00000278     SUBROUTINE OPTION(MSQLOC,RAD,LOCR,RDASH,X,Y,FEQ,HALFCO,H,H1,IMBAL,
00000279    1 CRXN,RICH,LAMBDA,DU)
00000280     REAL REYLOC(100),EXP(100),Z(100),Y(3),LOCR,CUR(100),IMBAL,LDASH,
00000281    1LAT,LSCALE,U(100),TRAD(100),MSQLOC,LAMDA,LSQ,L1,L2,L3
00000282     INTEGER AX,CU,CO,FS,ST,DIL,P,DEV,JTE,RATIO
00000283     COMMON/CB1/AX,CU,CO,FS,ST,DIL,P,DEV,JTE,RATIO
00000284     COMMON/CB3/CUR,EXPR,REYLOC
00000285     COMMON/CB2/REC,TRAD,UDASH,Z,J,U,RK
00000286     IMBAL=0.0000
00000287     RSLOPE=0.0000
00000288     RICH=0.0
00000289     DPHIDZ=0.0
00000290     CRXN=0.0000
00000291     L1=1.0
00000292     L2=1.0
00000293     L3=1.0
00000294     SW4=1+0.2*REC*MSQLOC
00000295     ZDIFF=Z(J)-Z(J-1)
00000296     IF(CO.EQ.0)GOTO 2
00000297     LDASH=(REYLOC(J)-REYLOC(J-1))/ZDIFF
00000298     RDE=(EXPR(J)/REYLOC(J)-EXPR(J-1)/REYLOC(J-1))/ZDIFF
00000299     IMBAL=RDE-RDASH
00000300     CRXN=-IMBAL*2*(H1*(Y(1)-1)-Y(1))/(2*Y(1)-1)
00000301     IF(J.GT.JTE)GOTO 4
00000302 2   IF(CU.EQ.0.AND.ST.EQ.0.AND.DIL.EQ.0)GOTO 5
00000303     IF(CU.EQ.0)GOTO 3
00000304     CURV=CUR(J-1)+(CUR(J)-CUR(J-1))*(X-Z(J-1))/ZDIFF
00000305     RICH=0.6667*(1+0.2*MSQLOC)*(0.3+H1/Y(1))*Y(2)*(H1+H)*CURV/RAD
00000306 3   IF(ST.EQ.0)GOTO 4
00000307     DPHIDZ=-IMBAL/Y(2)/(2*Y(1)-1)
00000308     RSLOPE=(TRAD(J)-TRAD(J-1))/(ZDIFF*RAD)
00000309 4   ALPHA=4.5
00000310     IF(CURV.GT.0.0)ALPHA=7.0
00000311     L1=1+ALPHA*RICH
00000312     IF(ST.EQ.1)L2=1-2.33*(H1/Y(1)+0.3)*(H+H1)*Y(2)/RAD*(DPHIDZ+RSLOPE
00000313    1)
00000314     IF(DIL.EQ.1)L3=1+2.33*MSQLOC*(1+H1/Y(1))*DU/RAD
00000315     LAMDA=L1*L2*L3
00000316     IF(J.GT.JTE)LAMDA=0.5
00000317     IF(LAMDA.LT.0.499)LAMDA=0.499
00000318     LSQ=LAMDA*LAMDA
00000319     C=0.5333*HALFCO*(1-1/LSQ)-0.02*FEQ/LSQ-FEQ*FEQ/LSQ
00000320     IF(C.GT.0.0000999)C=0.0000999
00000321     FEQ=SQRT(0.0001-C)-0.01
00000322 5   RETURN
00000323     END
00000324     
00000325     SUBROUTINE EVALFP(PINF,HQINF,REC,Q,V,MSQ,U,P,REYLOC,PH,CP,RK)
00000326     REAL MINF,V(100),MINFSQ,U(100),MSQ(100),REYLOC(100),Q(100),
00000327    1PH(100),CP(100),RK(100)
00000328     INTEGER P,TQ,HQ
00000329     COMMON/CB4/MINFSQ,TINF,RC
00000330     COMMON/CB6/MINF,TSTAG,M,TQ,HQ,IRPT,IDENT,KK,HDASH
00000331     MINFSQ=MINF*MINF
00000332     TR=1.0+0.2*MINFSQ
00000333     PINF=TR**(-3.5)
00000334     HQINF=TR**3.5/(0.7*MINFSQ)
00000335     TINF=TSTAG/TR
00000336     GOTO(1,2,3,4,5),M
00000337 1   DO 10 JJ=1,P
00000338     MSQ(JJ)=MINFSQ*V(JJ)*V(JJ)/(1.0+0.2*MINFSQ*(1.0-V(JJ)*V(JJ)))
00000339     CALL COMPTU(M,MSQ,U,V,TR,REYLOC,JJ,Q,CP,PH,PINF,HQINF)
00000340 10  CONTINUE
00000341     GOTO 5
00000342 2   DO 11 JJ=1,P
00000343     QQ=1.0+0.7*MINFSQ*V(JJ)
00000344     MSQ(JJ)=5.0*(TR*QQ**(-0.2857143)-1.0)
00000345     CALL COMPTU(M,MSQ,U,V,TR,REYLOC,JJ,Q,CP,PH,PINF,HQINF)
00000346 11  CONTINUE
00000347     GOTO 5
00000348 3   DO 12 JJ=1,P
00000349     MSQ(JJ)=5.0*(V(JJ)**(-0.2857143)-1.0)
00000350     CALL COMPTU(M,MSQ,U,V,TR,REYLOC,JJ,Q,CP,PH,PINF,HQINF)
00000351 12  CONTINUE
00000352     GOTO 5
00000353 4   DO 13 JJ=1,P
00000354     MSQ(JJ)=V(JJ)*V(JJ)
00000355     CALL COMPTU(M,MSQ,U,V,TR,REYLOC,JJ,Q,CP,PH,PINF,HQINF)
00000356 13  CONTINUE
00000357 5   RETURN
00000358     END
00000359     
00000360     SUBROUTINE COMPTU(M,MSQ,U,V,TR,REYLOC,JJ,Q,CP,PH,PINF,HQINF)
00000361     COMMON/CB4/MINFSQ,TINF,RC
00000362     REAL MSQ(100),MINFSQ,U(100),V(100),REYLOC(100),Q(100),PH(100),
00000363    1CP(100)
00000364     IF(M-1)3,1,3
00000365 3   U(JJ)=SQRT(TR*MSQ(JJ)/(MINFSQ*(1.0+0.2*MSQ(11))))
00000366     GOTO 2
00000367 1   U(JJ)=V(JJ)
00000368 2   TLOC=TINF*(1+0.2*MINFSQ)/(1.0+0.2*MSQ(JJ))
00000369     REYLOC(JJ)=RC*U(JJ)*TLOC/TINF*(TLOC+114)/(TINF+114)
00000370     Q(JJ)=U(JJ)*U(JJ)*(TLOC/TINF)**2.5
00000371     PH(JJ)=(1+0.2*MSQ(JJ))**(-3.5)
00000372     CP(JJ)=(PH(JJ)-PINF)*HQINF
00000373     RETURN
00000374     END
00000375     
00000376     SUBROUTINE INDATA(Z,Z1,XX,CUR,PH,CP,MSQ,U,Q,SURF,AXIS,P,CURV,
00000377    1OUT,RK)
00000378     REAL Z(100),Z1(100),XX(100),CUR(100),PH(100),CP(100),RMSQ(100),
00000379    1MSQ(100),U(100),Q(100),RK(100)
00000380     INTEGER SURF,CURV,AXIS,P,OUT
00000381     DO 15 J=1,P
00000382     RMSQ(J)=SQRT(MSQ(J))
00000383 15  CONTINUE
00000384     IF(SURF.GT.0.OR.AXIS.GT.0)GOTO 1
00000385     IF(CURV.GT.0)GOTO 2
00000386     WRITE(OUT,20)
00000387     WRITE(OUT,10)(Z(J),CP(J),PH(J),RMSQ(J),U(J),Q(J),RK(J),J=1,P)
00000388     RETURN
00000389 2   WRITE(OUT,21)
00000390     WRITE(OUT,11)(Z(J),CUR(J),CP(J),PH(J),RMSQ(J),U(J),Q(J),J=1,P)
00000391     RETURN
00000392 1   IF(AXIS.GT.0)GOTO 3
00000393     IF(CURV.GT.0)GOTO 4
00000394     WRITE(OUT,22)
00000395     GOTO 6
00000396 4   WRITE(OUT,23)
00000397     GOTO 7
00000398 3   IF(CURV.GT.9)GOTO 5
00000399     WRITE(OUT,24)
00000400 6   WRITE(OUT,12)(Z1(J),XX(J),Z(J),CP(J),PH(J),RMSQ(J),U(J),Q(J),
00000401    1RK(J),J=1,P)
00000402     RETURN
00000403 5   WRITE(OUT,25)
00000404 7   DO 16 J=1,P
00000405     WRITE(OUT,13)Z1(J),XX(J),Z(J),CUR(J),CP(J),PH(J),RMSQ(J),
00000406    1U(J),Q(J)
00000407 16  CONTINUE
00000408     RETURN
00000409 10  FORMAT(1H ,20X,1PE11.4,3X,0PF10.4,3X,F7.5,5X,F6.4,5X,F7.4,3X,
00000410    1F10.4,3X,1PE11.4)
00000411 11  FORMAT(1H ,20X,1PE11.4,5X,E11.4,3X,0PF10.4,3X,F7.5,5X,F6.4,5X,F7.4
00000412    1,5X,F10.4)
00000413 12  FORMAT(1H ,10X,1PE11.4,5X,E11.4,5X,E11.4,3X,0PF10.4,3X,F7.5,5X,
00000414    1F6.4,5X,F7.4,3X,F10.4,3X,F7.4)
00000415 13  FORMAT(1H ,4X,1PE11.4,4X,E11.4,4X,E11.4,4X,E11.4,2X,0PF10.4,2X,
00000416    1F7.5,4X,F6.4,4X,F7.4,2X,F10.4)
00000417 20  FORMAT(1H0,25X,1HX,13X,2HCP,9X,3HP/H,9X,1HM,8X,6HU/UREF,6X,
00000418    16HQ/QREF,6X,2HRK)
00000419 21  FORMAT(1H0,25X,1HX,14X,5HLCURV,10X,2HCP,9X,3HP/H,9X,1HM,8X,
00000420    16HU/UREF,6X,6HQ/QREF)
00000421 22  FORMAT(1H0,15X,1HX,15X,1HZ,15X,1HS,13X,2HCP,9X,3HP/H,9X,1HM,8X,
00000422    16HU/UREF,6X,6HQ/QREF)
00000423 23  FORMAT(1H0,10X,1HX,14X,1HZ,14X,1HS,13X,5HLCURV,9X,2HCP,8X,3HP/H,
00000424    18X,1HM,7X,6HU/UREF,5X,6HQ/QREF)
00000425 24  FORMAT(1H0,15X,1HX,14X,3HRAD,14X,1HS,13X,2HCP,9X,3HP/H,9X,1HM,
00000426    18X,6HU/UREF,6X,6HQ/QREF,6X,2HRK)
00000427 25  FORMAT(1H0,10X,1HX,13X,3HRAD,13X,1HS,13X,5HLCURV,9X,2HCP,8X,
00000428    13HP/H,8X,1HM,7X,6HU/UREF,5X,6HQ/QREF)
00000429     END
00000430     
00000431     SUBROUTINE STEP(YDASH,Y,DEL)
00000432     REAL YDASH(3),Y(3),S(3)
00000433     DO 1 I=1,3
00000434     IF(ABS(YDASH(I)).LT.0.1E-05)YDASH(I)=0.1E-05
00000435 1   CONTINUE
00000436     VAR=0.01
00000437     S(1)=ABS(VAR/YDASH(1))
00000438     S(2)=ABS(VAR*Y(2)/YDASH(2))
00000439     S(3)=DEL*VAR
00000440     DEL=S(1)
00000441     DO 2 I=1,3
00000442     IF(S(I).LT.DEL)DEL=S(I)
00000443 2   CONTINUE
00000444     RETURN
00000445     END
00000446     
00000447     SUBROUTINE CUORAX(AXIS,CURV,P,RSTAR,RI,Z1,LS,OUT)
00000448     REAL RSTAR(100),RI(100),Z1(100)
00000449     INTEGER AXIS,CURV,P,OUT
00000450     IF(AXIS.EQ.1.AND.CURV.GT.0)GOTO 1
00000451     IF(AXIS.EQ.0)GOTO 2
00000452     WRITE(OUT,20)
00000453     WRITE(OUT,10)(Z1(J),RSTAR(J),J=LS,P)
00000454     RETURN
00000455 2   WRITE(OUT,21)
00000456     WRITE(OUT,10)(Z1(J),RI(J),J=LS,P)
00000457     RETURN
00000458 1   WRITE(OUT,22)
00000459     WRITE(OUT,12)(Z1(J),RSTAR(J),RI(J),J=LS,P)
00000460     RETURN
00000461 10  FORMAT(1H ,1PE11.4,5X,E13.6)
00000462 12  FORMAT(1H ,1PE11.4,5X,E13.6,5X,E13.6)
00000463 20  FORMAT(///1H0,6X,1HX,13X,7HR*THETA)
00000464 21  FORMAT(///1H0,6X,1HX,9X,14HRICHARDSON NO.)
00000465 22  FORMAT(///1HO,6X,1HX,13X,7HR*THETA,7X,14HRICHARDSON NO.)
00000466     END
00000467     
00000468     SUBROUTINE VINT(N,H,X,Y,XD,E,NS,DY,RK,N7,OUT,J)
00000469     INTEGER QD,QDP,TD,TDP,V0,VE,U0,RD,OUT,LL
00000470     DIMENSION Y(N),DY(N),RK(N7)
00000471 1   IF(ABS(XD-X).LT.1E-20)GOTO 100
00000472     IF(ABS(H).LT.1E-20)GOTO 100
00000473     G0=5*E
00000474     ED=0.03125*G0
00000475 2   V0=0
00000476     GOTO 23
00000477 3   QD=0
00000478     H0=0
00000479 9   X0=X
00000480     F0=XD-X
00000481     Y0=F0-H
00000482     IF(H.GT.0.)GOTO 10
00000483     Y0=-Y0
00000484 10  IF(Y0.GT.0.)GOTO 11
00000485     HD=F0
00000486     U0=-1
00000487     GOTO 12
00000488 11  HD=H
00000489     U0=0
00000490 12  V0=V0+1
00000491     IF(V0.GT.NS) GOTO 100
00000492     QDP=QD+1
00000493 13  DO 22 TDP=QDP,7,1
00000494     TD=TDP-1
00000495     X=X0+H0
00000496     IF(TD.EQ.QD) GOTO 15
00000497     CALL FUNC(N,DY,X,Y,J)
00000498 15  DO 21 RD=1,N,1
00000499     GOTO (120,121,122,123,124,125,126),TDP
00000500 120     RK(5*N*RD)=Y(RD)
00000501     GOTO 21
00000502 121     RK(RD)=HD*DY(RD)
00000503     H0=0.5*HD
00000504     F0=0.5*RK(RD)
00000505     GOTO 20
00000506 122     RK(N+RD)=HD*DY(RD)
00000507     F0=0.25*(RK(RD)+RK(N+RD))
00000508     GOTO 20
00000509 123     RK(2*N+RD)=HD*DY(RD)
00000510     H0=HD
00000511     F0=-RK(N+RD)+2.*RK(2*N+RD)
00000512     GOTO 20
00000513 124     RK(3*N+RD)=HD*DY(RD)
00000514     H0=0.66666666667*HD
00000515     F0=(7.*RK(RD)+10.*RK(N+RD)+RK(3*N+RD))/27.
00000516     GOTO 20
00000517 125     RK(4*N+RD)=HD*DY(RD)
00000518     H0=0.2*HD
00000519     F0=(28.*RK(RD)-125.*RK(N+RD)+546.*RK(2*N+RD)+54.*RK(3*N+RD)-
00000520    1378.*RK(4*N+RD))/625.
00000521     GOTO 20
00000522 126     RK(6*N+RD)=HD*DY(RD)
00000523     F0=0.1666666667*(RK(RD)+4.*RK(2*N+RD)+RK(3*N+RD))
00000524     X=X0+HD
00000525     ER=(-42.*RK(RD)-224.*RK(2*N+RD)-21.*RK(3*N+RD)+162.*RK(4*N+RD)
00000526    1+125.*RK(6*N+RD))/67.2
00000527     YN=RK(5*N+RD)+F0
00000528     IF(ABS(YN).LT.1E-8) YN=1
00000529     ER=ABS(ER/YN)
00000530     IF(ER.GT.G0) GOTO 115
00000531     IF(ED.GT.ER) GOTO 20
00000532     QD=-1
00000533 20  Y(RD)=RK(5*N+RD)+F0
00000534 21  CONTINUE
00000535 22  CONTINUE
00000536     IF(QD.LT.0)GOTO 23
00000537     IF(U0.LT.0)GOTO 23
00000538     H=2.*H
00000539 23  F0=XD-X
00000540     IF(H.GT.0) GOTO 25
00000541     F0=-F0
00000542 25  IF(F0.GT.0.)GOTO 3
00000543     RETURN
00000544 115     DO 24 RD=1,N
00000545     DY(RD)=RK(RD)/HD
00000546 24  CONTINUE
00000547     H=0.5*HD
00000548     QD=1
00000549     GOTO 11
00000550 100     WRITE(OUT,101)H,XD,X,VO
00000551 101     FORMAT(19H VINT HAS FAILE H=,E11.4,3HXD=,E11.4,2HX=,E11.4,3HV0=,
00000552    1I4)
00000553     STOP
00000554 102     RETURN
00000555     END
00000556     
00000557     SUBROUTINE SFCR(HALFC,RK,AAA)
00000558     REAL Y1,Y2,K1,K2,AAA,NUM,DEN
00000559     Y1=HALFC
00000560     K1=2.439*ALOG(RK)-3.0-(1.0/SQRT(HALFC))
00000561     K2=1.2195
00000562 5   NUM=SQRT(Y1)+Y1*(K1+(K2*ALOG(Y1)))
00000563     DEN=K1/2.0+K2*(1.0+(ALOG(Y1))/2.0)
00000564     Y2=Y1-NUM/DEN
00000565     IF (ABS((Y2-Y1)/Y2).LT.0.000001) GOTO 10
00000566     Y1=Y2
00000567     GOTO 5
00000568 10  AAA=Y2/HALFC
00000569     RETURN
00000570     END
```

Comment: Hi, sorry - this is my first post on stack exchange. I've made the changes you suggested.

Comment: First thing would be to use flag -Wall and concentrate on the warnings you get from compiler. For example, it would have warned you about truncated lines. Then I would recommend using ftnchek, or if you have some money forcheck, they would probably have told you about the errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, some thoughts:

I suspect that the error at line 412 is that line 411 is too long.  Vintage FORTRAN had strict limits on line lengths, essentially all the code had to be in columns 7:72.  The code you've posted includes many lines with a character (usually a `1` as it happens but old FORTRAN doesn't really care what character is used) in column 6.  Line 412 is an example of this.  This *continuation character* tells the compiler that line 412 continues line 411.  I think that what has happened here is that line 411 extends beyond column 72 and the compiler ignores any characters in positions 73 or later so when it reads the continuation it finds a mal-formed statement.  I suggest you take the last few characters on line 411 and transfer them to line 412.

If my suspicion is correct that should fix your latter 2 errors.

I can't really see the problem that is causing the first of your errors.  So, in the best traditions of debugging, I vaguely assert that it may be an error earlier in the code that the compiler fails to diagnose correctly.

The first of your warnings

```
Warning: Type mismatch in argument 'imbalcrxn'
```

is actually a subtle error.  Your code doesn't define a variable called `imbalcrxn`, though it does define variables called `imbal` and `crxn`.  For some reason your compiler has, firstly, not noticed the comma separating those two variable names across the continuation, and, secondly, because Fortran will, unless you tell it otherwise, allow you to refer to undeclared variables and implicitly type them for you.  Here you have inadvertently created a variable called `imbalcrxn` which, because its name begins with an `i` has been given type of default integer.  And, because of the vintage of your code, the mismatch between actual and dummy arguments goes unchecked.

You can probably fix this by moving the comma at the end of line 249 to position 7 on line 250.

I think the warning at line 122 is also due to a too-long line.

Now it's time for my dinner, if I have time later I'll swing by and see how far you've got.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! I have managed to compile it based on your advice on column widths. The first error occurred due to a typo.

Answer (score 1):

expr is not declared as an array in subroutine option.
Likely EXP(100) is a typo should be EXPR(100) on line 280.

The symbol EXP is never used, and what a horrible choice of an array name if it is, I'm surprised there isnt some conflicting with intrinsic type of error/warning.

All of your arrays that appear in common need to also be declared properly as arrays in each subroutine where they are used.  The error says "EXPR isnt an array (not declared so)  so it must be a function (procedure), but then It cant be a function either because its in common."

By the way they are using DEXP as an array. I'd globally change that to something else,
just watch your line length if you use a longer name.

Comment: Thanks, you're right EXP should be EXPR. I have also changed DEXP to DEXPR - having read further I see that in old versions of fortran DEXP is an exponential function for double precision numbers.